# Add an object (4 String variables in a single row) to JList in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to add an object to a JList in java. The object has 4 variables which need to be in a single row of JList (represent the values within one object) --> meaning that each object will have its information listed in a single row. I've tried with the default list model but an item gets inserted in JList in this format: classOfObject@1cf3d4e

```
public  static void addElementToList(JList list, Object obj){


   DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();

   int size = list.getModel().getSize();
   for (int i=0;i<size;i++){

      dlm.addElement(list.getModel().getElementAt(i));

  }
   dlm.addElement(obj);
   list.setModel(dlm);
}
```

And I get this as a result:
[image]

Comment: You're seeing Object's default `public String toString()` in your JList. The quick and dirty way to solve this is to override your Airline class's toString() method to return something that you want to display, but the better solution is as per Camickr's answer in the 2nd duplicate -- to use a custom renderer.

Comment: Yeepp it works. I overrided the to string method and know is okay it displays the info the objects have. Thank you very much